# Design a Real FIR with arbitrary Phase Response

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, phase

## Intro

My question is related to this one: [Correcting phase response of a signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72158/correcting-phase-response-of-a-signal).

I need to design an FIR low-pass filter  with real coefficients for data received from a sensor. An additional requirement is to try and equalize to phase distortion introduced by the sensor (we have measurements of it).

While I could in theory design an allpass in addition to the low pass, I prefer not to as I care about the overall delay more than the distortion.

However, I thought maybe I can design a single filter doing both low-pass and phase equalization.
I will consider the solution suggested by Matt [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/72173/35390), but first I thought of a simple solution which already builds on FIR which I designed and I'm happy with. Can't I simply:

1. Take the frequency response of the filter I have
2. Multiply the positive frequencies by  the by the desired phase response, and negative ones by the conjugate.
3. Take the inverse transform (`invfreqz`) to find filter taps

## Questions

1. How does this approach compare to LS or complex PM design algorithms?
2. My intuition is that this approach (given the the LPF was designed using `firls`), will maintain its performance as a low pass, and will somewhat sacrifice the phase performance as it hasn't been optimized in any sense. Am I correct?
3. It sounds as if I'm getting here "something for free" and we all know there are no free lunches when it comes to engineering. What am I sacrificing compared to the original LPF?
4. I've stumbled upon some notions that such arbitrary phase FIRs aren't necessarily causal. Obviously the group delay of my filter will be altered (this is my goal by adding phase, not a consequence). How will the resulting filter be non-causal? I assume it it happens if the phase is large enough compared to the linear phase of the original filter? If so, assuming added phase is smaller than the $N/2$ delay of the FIR, I don't see  an issue. Am I missing something?
5. What will happen to the temporal characteristics of the filter, such as ringing effects, overshoot and undershoots?

The only draw back I found so far is the since the resulting filter will not be symmetric (by design), I cannot save hardware taps by exploiting symmetry.

## Update

So I tied both `lslevin`, trimming the IFFT, and `invfreqz` (both with weights provided and without them, as the documentation states the algorithm used is different). Attached are frequency response and group delay plots of the results, both for a $N=17$ order filter and for a $N=35$ order filter.

Surprisingly, there are fundamental differences which I do not understand intuitively.

1. For some reason the magnitude response of the of the non-linear phase filter has better noise rejection than the linear phase, but only for the short filter. Obviously the standard LS design is optimal only as long as the problem is constrained to linear phase filter, so the better noise rejection for the non-linear phase filter is understandable, but why does it occur only for the shorter filter?
2. For the $N=17$ filter GD approximation is quite bad, but it is better with the unweighted `invfreqz` and IFFT. For the longer filter the weighted variant approaches the GD approximation performance of the other two within passband. Is there an intuitive/fundamental reason for this, or is it a coincidence?

$N=17$ plots
[image]
[image]

$N=35$ plots
[image]
[image]

Comment: By *"real FIR"*, I presume you mean real-valued coefficients.  Does this *real FIR* also have to be realizable in real-time?  If so, that means it's ***causal*** and that means it cannot have any impulse response occurring before the impulse input.  That places constraints on the *arbitrary phase response.*

Comment: Indeed I meant real taps, and yes it must be also causal, but we can add an additional linear phase (delay).

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider here

`invfreqz` will give you an IIR filter, not and FIR filter. The underlying algorithm is numerically challenging so the results can be all over the place. For example in audio processing you will often poles that are extremely close to $z=1$ and `invfreqz` can't handle this.

If you want an FIR you can simply specify your response (magnitude and phase) on  conjugate symmetric FFT frequency grid and do an inverse FFT. Results will vary with the filter specification. You may see a lot of non-causality and pre- and post-ringing. It's typically best to start with a really long FFT and than see how much can be trimmed down to an acceptable length with acceptable accuracy.

The main downside of the FFT is that you have to specify the target at ALL frequencies, even for those you don't care about. For example, you need to specify the exact shape of the transition band, even if you don't care how exactly looks like.

A Least Squared Error approach will give you the best results within any given set of constraints simply because you get to define exactly what "best" means. By adjusting the frequency grid and weighting certain frequency ranges differently, you can optimize the filter performance for your specific application.

In the end it comes down to what works for your specific problem. You can start with the inverse FFT approach and if that's "good enough", you are done. A custom LS approach will give you better results, but it's also a lot more work.

**EDIT: a note on FIR allpass filters**

A true allpass filter, i.e. $|H(z) = 1|$ can only have zero/pole pairs that are inverse of each other. Since an FIR filter has all its poles at $z = 0$, the zeros of an FIR allpass must all be at $z=\infty$. It directly follows that any FIR allpass can only be a delay, i.e. $H(z) =  z^{-N}$

Comment: But `invfreqz` can return an FIR, you specify the order, nor problem to specify the order of the denominator as 0. Is there a reason not to do this? Given I use this, all stability issue become irrelevant.

Comment: Regarding your statement about optimality, what if the specified magnitude of the frequency response is already optimal in the LS sense? I designed a LPF of the required order using LS design, and now I want to alter the phase response by adding a frequency dependent phase. The reason I consider this approach to begin with, is that it will maintain the optimal magnitude of the response, will it not?

Comment: @YairM In general, the magnitude and phase responses of a FIR filter are interrelated and cannot be changed independently. You will get the best results if you design your filter in one shot using your actual desired response without the use of a "template filter." For a non-linear phase LS optimal filter, I would indeed suggest using `lslevin` as you've already found. (It's possible `invfreqz` would also work, I just don't have any experience with it.)

Comment: @YairM: that doesn't work since the only FIR allpass filters that exist are pure delays. If you need a phase correction that's different from a delay, you are out of luck with FIR. See my edited answer. You are indeed better off designing phase and magnitude in one go.

Comment: @Hilmar but I don’t want an all pass. I want a low pass to reject out-of-band noise (prior to decimation), and I want it with a non-linear phase, to have phase correction. I already have a linear phase LPF that I’m happy with, and I want phase equalization without additional taps, which is why I ruled out an extra low pass.

Comment: @JasonC doesn't Levin mean I need to specify the phase also in the don't care region? I don't care about the phase in the stop band. Can I specify phase only in the pass band?

Comment: I believe this can be done with an FIR filter with independent phase and amplitude adjustment for very nearly “all pass” as long as overall delay is not a constraint (up to 90% of the bandwidth if it was necessary). I do refer to those FIR filters as all-pass for practical purposes even though Hilmar is correct that it isn’t a “true all-pass”.  An FIR approach can be attractive / preferred for many reasons.

Comment: @YairM I think `lslevin` would work for your purposes. Transition bands can be omitted from the frequency grid and the stopband will have a complex desired response of "0", which is effectively a "don't care" for stopband phase.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything Hilmar wrote and want to add one more approach that is quite applicable to the OP’s objective:

Instead of using least squares (or any other approach) to meet a frequency response objective, use least squares with input (stimulus) and output (response) for the channel to be equalized. As long as the input is a proper sounding signal- meaning it has energy spread evenly over the bandwidth of interest (such as a frequency chirp or pseudo-random sequence) and the duration significantly exceeds the delay spread of the channel then the post-processing is quite straightforward (just a few lines of code in Matlab/Octave or Python. I detail the approach here including the code to use:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/31326/21048

This readily provides the FIR filter coefficients which will equalize both the phase and amplitude distortion (linear distortions) of the channel (or the device the signal passes through).  If the target frequency response for equalization was also determined from such measurements (such as a network analyzer or other channel probing technique), this technique would be more direct in operating on the original data to determine the equalizer needed.

Comment: The suggestion to use an LMS equalizer is indeed interesting. I have two questions though. I'm not sure what is my "transmitted signal" in case as you suggested I have a frequency and phase response measurements taken on a network analyzer.

Comment: My second question has to do with the general applicability of the LMS to my use case. I already have a low pass filter designed since I intend to oversample and then decimate. Thus, I need a single filter doing both noise rejection (LPF) and equalization (as I'm constrained to a specific overall filter length). Thus, I wanted to modify the exiting filter. Can I use the LMS result to modify the existing filter?

Comment: @YairM In that case your "transmitted signal" (Tx) would be a frequency chirp-specifically the complex baseband equivalent of the frequency chirp as it passes through your bandpass equivalent signal.   Yes if you have the Tx and Rx of the channel alone from the analyzer then you can determine the equalizer, filter that with a linear phase filter to emphasize the passband of interest, and then with the minimum representation of that required impulse response at your LPF sampling rate, you can convolve those coefficients to combine the result.

Comment: Although I suspect your network analyzer measurement is of very high SNR such that I doubt what I suggest would be any better than just taking the IFFT of the resulting complex frequency response, and then decimating that - I'll add some color to this in my answer above; but first can you confirm that you are sweeping an RF passband, for a signal that will be down-converted to complex baseband (where your low pass filter is)? Or do you really only have a real baseband?

Comment: I do not have a low pass pass equivalent which is modulated around some carrier. My signal has a BW of several hundreds of MHz and starts from DC. Thus I really have a real baseband signal.

Comment: Ok interesting, I need to think further about what might be the best approach— it sounds like you have a low noise estimate of what you need for a response - could you post the frequency response you are trying to equalize (magnitude and phase)? Unfortunately I am going to have limited time for the next 2 weeks but am interested in what you are doing / will do

Comment: I added a plot of the desired GD (linear phase plus some non-linearity corrections), as well as solution attempts.

Comment: @YairM I want you to know I am interested in this, along with reviewing again some "tricks" I learned from MattL on techniques to force the LS solution to be real (if that was desired). I'm going away this week and then will be very busy catching up on things so it will likely be a couple weeks before I have time--- please remind me if I lose track of this.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I remind you if needed. Note that I also asked a follow-up question following Matt's thesis, where I try try yet another approach. Linking here for you to find: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88969/least-squares-filter-with-non-linear-phase-and-independent-weights-for-phase-and