# Least squares filter with non-linear phase and independent weights for phase and magnitude

Tags: filter-design, optimization, least-squares, optimal-filter

## Intro

My question is related to a previous one linked [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/design-a-real-fir-with-arbitrary-phase-response).
I am interested in non-linear phase FIR filters with a specific desired phase response.

After I tried the options in the linked question I also stumbled upon the idea to separately define weights for phase and magnitude responses developed in Matt's PhD thesis linked [here](https://mattsdsp.blogspot.com/p/phd-thesis.html) (see section 2.1.3).

The thesis states that a discrete approximation variant can be similarly developed which is what I'm after. While Matt provides a MATLAB implementation, it follows the continuous approximation, and therefore the desired phase response is limited, and only allows for resampling data (fractional delay filter). On the other hand, I have measurements of the required phase response on a grid.

## Question

When I try to formulate the problem on a discrete frequency grid I get to a problem. After applying the approximation, the contribution of passband to approximation error reads:

$$\tilde\epsilon_p =
\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\left(W_m(\omega_i)\{Re[\mathbf{e}^H(\omega_i)\mathbf{h}e^{-j\phi_d(\omega_i)}]-|D(e^{j\omega_i})|\}^2  + W_\phi(\omega_i)\{Im[\mathbf{e}^H(\omega_i)\mathbf{h}e^{-j\phi_d(\omega_i)}]\}^2\right)
$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed due to the separate treatment of the real and imaginary parts. How would I get the normal equation form or solve it another way?